# execute npm install, when branching in TFS with Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs

Is there a way I can hook an `npm install` when I branch in Source Control explorer? Or if I can access a powershell window to run a script to do that for  me?

Comment: What's the detail mean of hook an npm install ? Did you mean this https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#hook-scripts  `If you want to run a specific script at a specific lifecycle event for ALL packages, then you can use a hook script.`

Comment: sorry for being unclear, didn't mean hook as in NPM's `/.hooks`. Wanted to execute a script when I branch in Source Control Explorer

Comment: So you want to run "npm install" command after create a branch?

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT yes, I want to automate npm install when I branch in TFS. Essentially

Comment: Not exactly what you are asking for, but you could try and use the node js TaskRunner-Extension in VS and register `npm install` to run when you load the project.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to run npm install when you create branch. If you have a large amount of projects need to run npm install after branch, you can create a powershell or batch script to do this just as you mentioned in your question.

Comment: well that sucks, oh well :/

Answer (score 0):

You can try do this through *a custom Check-in policy*. After branching in Source Control explorer, you need to check in the pending changes. These check-in policies require the user to take actions when they conduct a check-in to source control, for example a user can be required to associate a work item with a changeset.

About how to create a custom check-in policy you can refer the detailed answer from *jessehouwing* in this [TFS Client side hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25801982/tfs-client-side-hook) . You can also take a look at this blog [Creating TFS Custom Check-in Policy](http://blog.devart.com/creating-tfs-custom-check-in-policy-part-1.html)

Comment: will take a look and see if it aligns with my case!

Comment: Looked at it, I don't need to do npm install before checking in, I need it when I'm checking OUT, because I need to have all my dependencies in before I start developing