# Visual Studio Extension get CheckinComment

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I'm attempting to create a [custom checkin policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6140841/custom-check-in-policy-in-tfs/21485952#21485952) that verifies the checkin comment is in our standard format.

How would I get the CheckinComment text? Ideally I could also bind a onChange event to the text field. When debugging the extension I can see CheckinComment is a member of the PendingChanges object but I cannot access it because its a non-public property.

```
((Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Controls.PendingChanges.PendingChangesModel)PendingCheckin).CheckinComment
```

Using the extension debugger I can see the textbox is labeled "commentTextBox", is there an easy way of getting this controls value via a lable lookup?